# Printing Map in leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I want to print a map in `leaflet`,but i am stuck in some points:
**First**:The points (markers) didn't appear,
**Second**:i want to be able to define the scale in the printing time,
**Third**:i want to print the legend beside the map not on the map as in the picture below.
Can anyone help me?

```
L.easyPrint({
        title: 'Print the map',
        position: 'topleft',
        elementsToHide: 'p, h2,h3,h5,a,label,nav,select,button,i,legend'
    }).addTo(mymap);
```

[image]